# Uncaught type error with CoffeeScript and Backbone.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, backbone.js, coffeescript

Rails app, learning CoffeeScript and Backbone.js:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'id' in easy
_.extend.setbackbone.js:205
Backbone.Modelbackbone.js:142
Gamegames.js:13
(anonymous function)games.js:34
jQuery.Callbacks.firejquery.js:1047
jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWithjquery.js:1165
jQuery.extend.readyjquery.js:436
DOMContentLoadedjquery.js:924
```

Here is the code, games.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  root = global ? window
  class Game extends Backbone.Model
    initialize: (@n, @diff) ->
      console.log "--> Game.initialize()"
    difficulty: ->
      @diff
    name: ->
      @n
  # Make class Game globally available
  root.Game = Game
  my_game = new Game('easy', 'hard')
  console.log "my_game.name(), my_game.difficulty() --> #{my_game.name()}, #  {my_game.difficulty()}"
```

I am missing something, but having trouble figuring out what...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone model constructor functions expect a dictionary object with keys and values that will be set on that model.  You didn't provide an object, and instead provided 2 strings.  The error is cause by backbone trying to iterate through the object, but explodes because you can't legally do `for (key in "easy")`.

You also shouldn't be using properties for model data.  You should be using an object on instantiation or `set()` and `get()`.  So, if I may correct your code:

```
jQuery ->
  root = global ? window
  class Game extends Backbone.Model
    initialize: ->
      console.log "--> Game.initialize()"
    difficulty: ->
      @get 'diff'
    name: ->
      @get 'n'
  # Make class Game globally available
  root.Game = Game
  my_game = new Game n: 'easy', diff: 'hard'
  console.log "my_game.name(), my_game.difficulty() --> #{my_game.name()}, #{my_game.difficulty()}"
```

See this example working here: http://jsfiddle.net/NMkna/

Note how we no longer accept arguments in initialize now.  We can rely on backbone to set the proper attributes in the model, because we now pass in an object when creating the game.  And the methods we define simply `@get 'propname'` in order to retrieve those values.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot.  I suspected a syntax error.  I didn't see that in the Backbone.js docs, I will look again.

Comment: A syntax error wouldn't have a stack trace in javascript.  If there was a syntax error, the coffeescript would fail to compile at all.  That's an easy way to tell the difference.

Comment: If the conflation of CoffeeScript syntax (the initialize params) and Backbone.js syntax (the hash) doesn't produce a compile error, that doesn't mean it is syntactically correct.  Multilingual, and inaccurate.